# Merge data from two databases in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, cobol, jcl

I have a new requirement with me in which I have to merge data of two identical DB2 databases(around 200 tables in each) keeping all the unique rows from the both. these two databases are identical as they are from two different environment of same application and now clients wants them to merge together.

These tables are business tables, so they always have single records on the basis of Primary keys and foreign keys. which makes that there will be good chances of having the 2 records with same primary key when we will try to merge the databases. We only need to keep only single record out of these two records.

I am not getting a way to start doing this or how to proceed any Idea or approach will help, thanks in advance.

I have to prepare some set of JCLs which can use DB2 utilities, SQL or COBOL program to achieve this, but  I am not getting a way to start doing this or how to proceed .. any Idea or approach will help, thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad, you are basically asking us to come up an entire database merge solution. Come up with a plan and start working on it. When you hit an issue THEN come back and post a question. If you can't figure the best way to start, talk to your co-workers and get a feel for how they would approach the problem.

Comment: Since there's so much logic involved on merging each table, I don't see how you can easily do this using a tool. Maybe you'll need to divide and conquer. You'll need to write code to merge "dimension" tables first and then the main ones. But I see you'll need to code quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Both Syncsort and DFSORT have match merging capabilities, look for the JOIN control statement in the documentation.  Use your shop's DB2 unload utility to extract the data from each table into a flat file, then use your shop's SORT utility to match merge the two versions of each table, outputting matched records to one file, unmatched records from the first version to another file, and unmatched records from the second version to a third file.

This isn't difficult, just tedious.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but we are talking about around more than 250 tables with all different table structures and different keys, means have to prepare same JCLs with each key to match in Sort Join. Planning to write a dynamic SQL in a COBOL PGM which will take table name and get the keys information SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNs and take the unload from one DB and use the same to run queries on second DB. Matched records will be deleted and Unmatched records will be inserted and It will run for all tables in loop.